# Measuring objects in a photo taken by calibrated cameras, knowing the size of a reference object in the photo

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, geometry, perspectivecamera

I am writing a program that captures real time images from a scene by two calibrated cameras (so the internal parameters of the cameras are known to us). Using two view  geometry, I can find the essential matrix and use OpenCV or MATLAB to find the relative position and orientation of one camera with respect to another. Having the essential matrix, it is shown in Hartley and Zisserman's *Multiple View Geometry* that one can reconstruct the scene using triangulation up to scale. Now I want to use a reference length to determine the scale of reconstruction and resolve ambiguity.

I know the height of the front wall and I want to use it for determining the scale of reconstruction to measure other objects and their dimensions or their distance from the center of my first camera. How can it be done in practice?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** To add more information, I have already done linear trianglation (minimizing the algebraic error) but I am not sure if it is any useful because there is still a scale ambiguity that I don't know how to get rid of it. My ultimate goal is to recognize an object (like a Pepsi can) and separate it in a rectangular area (which is going to be written as a separate module by someone else) and then find the distance of each pixel in this rectangular area, i.e. the region of interest, to the camera. Then the distance from the camera to the object will be the minimum of the distances from the camera to the 3D coordinates of the pixels in the region of interest.

Comment: Are you trying to find distance of some specific pixels or whole scene?
    
Edit:Have you done all steps, including triangulation, finding your reference point in image and finding objects you want to measure distance or you are stuck at some step?

Comment: @unlut I'm trying to find the distance of some specific pixels. The idea is that I will do some object recognition to find the object of interest and then I will report the closest distance in a box engulfing the object as the distance between the camera and the object. Sorry that I didn't make it clear in my question. Let me edit my post to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but at least for someone struggling with the same staff.

As far as I remember it is actually linear problem. You got essential matrix, which gives you rotation matrix and normalized translation vector specifying relative position of cameras. If you followed Hartley and Zissermanm you probably chose one of the cameras as origin of world coordinate system. Meaning all your triangulated points are in normalized distance from this origin. What is important is, that the **direction** of every triangulated point is correct.

If you have some reference in the scene (lets say height of the wall), then you just have to find this reference (2 points are enough - so opposite ends of the wall) and calculate "normalization coefficient" (sorry for terminology) as

```
coeff = realWorldDistanceOf2Points / distanceOfTriangulatedPoints
```

Once you have this coeff, just mulptiply all your triangulated points with it and you got real world points.

Example:
you know that opposite corners of the wall are 5m from each other. you find these corners in both images, triangulate them (lets call triangulated points `c1` and `c2`), calculate their distance in the "normalized" world as ||`c1` - `c2`|| and get the

```
coeff = 5 / ||c1 - c2||
```

and you get real 3d world points as `triangulatedPoint*coeff`.

Maybe easier option is to have both cameras in fixed relative position and calibrate them together by `stereoCalibrate` openCV/Matlab function (there is actually pretty nice GUI in Matlab for that) - it returns not just intrinsic params, but also extrinsic. But I don't know if this is your case.